# borrar repetidos en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, delete

Buen día. Tengo esta tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y necesito borrar las referencias que estén repetidas y dejar un única referencia de articulo, obteniendo este resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy haciendo el `query` pero no se que condición colocar para borrar una sola linea:

```
tep_db_query("delete from " . TABLE . " where referencia ?????? ");
```

No se si utilizar algún `select count(*) as count`

El archivo viene de un `csv` exportado, se genera un id automáticamente, la lista es un excel que contiene varias columnas **referencia, descripcion, precio ean, etc**. Pero hay referencias repetidas y necesito es borrar la linea repetida y dejar una sola linea única.

Comment: ¿Esas son todas las columnas de tu tabla? ¿No tenes una columna con ID único?

Comment: si tengo una id pero el id no esta repetido en ningun momento

Comment: Mejor! Por favor, edita tu pregunta y agrega la definción de la tabla

Comment: Y si guardas en un array php el csv, luego haces un distinct del array y lo insertas?

Answer (score 2):

En base a [este comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/309378/borrar-repetidos-en-mysql?noredirect=1#comment563188_309378), podrías hacerlo así:

- Buscamos los `id` de los registros agrupados por `referencia`
- Eliminamos aquellos registros cuyo `id` no esté dentro de los obtenidos previamente

#### Ejemplo:

```
DELETE
FROM `tabla`
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM (
    SELECT id
    FROM tabla
    GROUP BY referencia
  ) AS t
);
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72edb58/1/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Segun lo que entiendo tienes varias posibilidades:

Si el csv viene con datos repetidos podrias eliminarlos antes de insertarlos

archivo.csv | sort | uniq > nuevo_archivo.csv

Si ya los insertaste en la tabla una opcion es limpiarla de la siguiente forma:

- Insertarlos a una tabla temporal agrupados :

Código

```
INSERT INTO tabla_sin_duplicados (Referencia, Descripcion)
   SELECT Referencia, Descripcion
   FROM Tabla_original
   GROUP BY Referencia, Descripcion;
```

- Renombrar:

Código

```
RENAME TABLE tabla_original TO tabla_duplicada , tabla_sin_duplicados TO tabla_original;
```

Para insertarlos desde el csv sin que se dupliquen:

- Crear un indice unico para prevenir la inserción de duplicados

Código

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_referencia_descripcion ON tabla(referencia,descripcion)
```

- insertar valores con ignore:

Código

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tabla( referencia,descripcion) VALUES( 1, 'other value' );
```

Y también puedes borrarlos de la siguiente forma, pero es poco eficiente si la tabla es muy grande:

```
DELETE from tabla 
where id not in (SELECT Referencia, Descripcion, min(id) 
FROM Tabla_original GROUP BY Referencia, Descripcion)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pides es imposible poderlo realizar con una consulta simple. 
La única solución es crear una tabla temporal, insertar los datos agrupados, eliminar los datos originales e insertarlos de nuevo desde la tabla temporal.

```
CREATE TABLE TablaTemporal(Referecnia VARCHAR(50), Descripcion VARCHAR(50), Cuantos INT);

INSERT INTO TablaTemporal (Referencia, Descripcion, Cuantos)
SELECT Referencia, Descripcion, count(*)
FROM Tabla
GROUP BY Referencia, Descripcion;

DELETE FROM Tabla;

INSERT INTO Tabla (Referencia, Descripcion)
SELECT Referencia, Descripcion
FROM TablaTemporal ;

DROP TABLE TablaTemporal ;
```

Por otra parte sería necesario establecer una clave primaria para tu tabla para evitar que eso vuelva a ocurrir.

Comment: es un archivo subido por csv, el id se genera solo las referencias se repiten pero los id no

Answer (score 1):

No hay una manera de hacer esto. Tienes que hacer lo que ha planteado Roger. Pero para evitar repeticiones pon una clave primaria en la referencia o en la referencia y la descripción dependiendo de lo que quieras guardar.